# Exclude records which does not meet condition in model in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, model, conditional-statements, eager-loading

I have multiple tables and their models which they have relation with each other named : `"users","posts","tags","comments"`.

I want to exclude data of `deactive` users from all of this models, and whenever any of this models has been called do not return users which are `deactive`

I don't want to exclude those "users" using eloquent or query builder in their controllers, I need to do this in model so it apply to all places which are using said models.

posts , comments and tags relation to users is :

```
 public function user()
 {
    return  $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User', 'user_id');
 }
```

I need something like this in related model:

```
$instance = $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User', 'user_id');
$instance->whereIsDeactive(0);//return active users only
return $instance;
```

And something like this in user model:

```
return $this->whereIsDeactive(0);
```

Is it possible and is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: look into using global scopes: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#global-scopes. If you add a `deactive` global scope on the user model, you should never get `deactive` users or related data through eager loading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Adam I solved the issue using global scopes.

This is `IsDeactive` global scope :

```
namespace App\Scopes;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Scope;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;

class IsDeactiveScope implements Scope
{
    /**
     * Apply the scope to a given Eloquent query builder.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder  $builder
     * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model  $model
     * @return void
     */
    public function apply(Builder $builder, Model $model)
    {
        $builder->where('is_deactive', 0);
    }
}
```

And this is how to call it in user model:

```
/**
     * The "booting" method of the model.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::addGlobalScope(new IsDeactiveScope());
    }
```

I hope this solution help others.